# What happens when rangeOfCharacterFromSet is called?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nscharacterset

What this following code mean, 
I know this is to avoid typing characters other than numbers in a TextField. But what is actually happening behind this function `rangeOfCharacterFromSet` . **What it will return.**

```
if ([string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]].location != NSNotFound)
        return NO;
```

In documentation it said

> Finds and returns the range in the receiver of the first character
>   from a given character set. The range in the receiver of the first
>   character found from aSet. Returns a range of {NSNotFound, 0} if none
>   of the characters in aSet are found

I can't even understand what is **receiver** And why **NSNotFound** is used here. And what is that **aSet**

Please explain me with some example for better understanding (Like what will happen when i press a character other than numbers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (void)test {
NSString *str = @"input content";
NSCharacterSet *characterSet = [NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet];
NSRange range = [str rangeOfCharacterFromSet:characterSet];
NSLog(@"location:%ld, length:%ld", range.location, range.length);
// range.location is 9223372036854775807, in fact it is a NSNotFound which means not exists, range.length is 0

str = @"input 1";
range = [str rangeOfCharacterFromSet:characterSet];
NSLog(@"location:%ld, length:%ld", range.location, range.length);
// range.location is 6, range.length is 1

str = @"input 123";
range = [str rangeOfCharacterFromSet:characterSet];
NSLog(@"location:%ld, length:%ld", range.location, range.length);
// range.location is 6, range.length is 1

str = @"123 input 123";
range = [str rangeOfCharacterFromSet:characterSet];
NSLog(@"location:%ld, length:%ld", range.location, range.length);
// range.location is 0, range.length is 1
}
```

In the test, str is the receiver, when you call a method, who call who is reciever: [receiver callTheMethod]. Abount NSCharacterSet, I think the document explains clearly:

> An NSCharacterSet object represents a set of Unicode-compliant characters. NSString and NSScanner objects use NSCharacterSet objects to group characters together for searching operations, so that they can find any of a particular set of characters during a search. The cluster’s two public classes, NSCharacterSet and NSMutableCharacterSet, declare the programmatic interface for static and dynamic character sets, respectively.

NSRange is the result of [str rangeOfCharacterFromSet:characterSet], it is a struct, range.location is the first index in str which is included in characterSet, it is a NSInteger type, when the str not exits a the content of characterSet it will be a very big integer, and it means NSNotFound. range.length means as the words, at here, it always is 1 unless range.location is NSNotFound.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Well, let me say it with this words: If you do not know, what a receiver is, you should read a beginner's book about Objective-C.

However, …

The receiver is the object, you send the message to. So make it a bit easier to understand:

```
NSCharacterSet *digits = [NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet];
[string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:digits];
```

In the first line you send the message `decimalDigitCharacterSet` to the class object of `NSCharacterSet`. In the second line you send the message `rangeOfCharacterFromSet:digits` to an instance object of `NSString`.

So let us translate the docs, step 1:

> Finds and returns the range in the string (formerly: receiver) of the first character from a given character set. The range in the receiver of the first character found from aSet. Returns a range of {NSNotFound, 0} if none of the characters in aSet are found

Since a range contains two plain integers, you cannot assign `nil` to them to mark an error. It would be 0. Therefore a magic number (`NSNotFound`) is assigned. However, don't care about this, just check the length on 0.

The set is the character set, a set containing the digits.

Answer (score 0):

What the code does is it returns `NO` if the string contains a character that isn't a number.

If you call `[myString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:mySet]`, `myString` is the `receiver` and `mySet` is the `aSet`.

`NSNotFound` is just an arbitrary constant that indicates that none of the characters in the set is found.